# Transpose Coordinates to UTM84-17N Projection

Tags: swift, mapkit, coordinates, projection, transpose

In Swift, is there a way to input Lat/Long coordinates from MapKit, and translate those coordinates to a specified Projection, such as UTM84-17N (e.g. AutoCAD format)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I never did figure out how to do this using iOS/Swift, but I did discover a lisp code in both AutoCAD Map (two or three lines of code) and even better, in BricsCAD using the Spatial Manager extension (One single line of code).
For both, they involve three parameters: the source coordinates (in my case are in lat/long) the source projection code and the destination projection code.
The projection codes lists are provided in 'help.'

Actually, the company who owns Spatial Manager actually wrote the routine to fit into lisp for me when I posed the question to them; amazing!
So, there might be a manageable method that can be written for any platform.., who knows.

If anyone is interested in those lines of code to work in CAD, I'll look them up and post them.

By the way, a plug for BricsCAD: AutoCAD MAP from Autodesk, is now like almost $10,000 Canadian; BricsCAD is far less than $1000 for their best Pro option. NO BRAINER. AND, I find after being a guru in AutoCAD scripting for years, that BricsCAD is way better! AutoCAD is now so full of bloatware trinkets and useless stuff (similar to Windows' verification window pop ups) that it takes about 30 seconds just to load on a fast rig. And they have made things so much more difficult for old school users. Not to mention, the folks at BricsCAD are so incredibly helpful you feel like family with them!
...only one tiny flaw so far in going with them tho. They don't have a proper lisp editor (that I can find anyway), that lets you test the code line by line real time - like AutoCAD does...